# How to compare one value, with a value that corresponds to another value?

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
Table 1
pizza     |price|country|base
-----------------------------------
americano | 2   | U.S   | wholemeal
funghi    | 3   | Italy | wholemeal
sicilliano| 7   | Italy | wholemeal
```

I need to list all the `pizza` elements, that have the same `country` element, as sicilliano `pizza`, not using a subquery.

Comment: You could self join it -> https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-self-join/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INNER JOIN` the same table see [manual about JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

As you don't want subquery, you circumvnt it, by using join, when you run

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.* FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.`country` = t2.`country`
```

You see tat for ever country row in t1 you find a row from t2.
So for siziliano in t1 you get funghi and siziliano in t2.

The rest is reducing all t2 rows, to the ones you need

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Table1 (
>   `pizza` VARCHAR(10),
>   `price` INTEGER,
>   `country` VARCHAR(5),
>   `base` VARCHAR(9)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO Table1
>   (`pizza`, `price`, `country`, `base`)
> VALUES
>   ('americano', '2', 'U.S', 'wholemeal'),
>   ('funghi', '3', 'Italy', 'wholemeal'),
>   ('sicilliano', '7', 'Italy', 'wholemeal');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT t2.`pizza` FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.`country` = t2.`country` WHERE t1.`pizza` = 'sicilliano'
> ```
>
> ```
> | pizza      |
> | :--------- |
> | funghi     |
> | sicilliano |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f9b5da785b08af0285783161ed27f8fa)*

Comment: May i ask for some more explanation?  I tried reading these manuals however, I can't seem to grasp it.

Comment: i added some explanation, in general show all column and so you see betrer what a join makes or the where clause

Comment: And if i wanted to list all the pizzas, that have higher prices, than a specific one?
SELECT  t2.pizza
FROM menu t1 INNER JOIN menu t2 ON t1.price = t2.price WHERE t1.price > 'americano';
I tried something like this, but obviously you can't compare string with integer

Comment: it is the same with a subquerz zou need to select the price of americano, with out zou need to join another table that filters everzthing out that is smaller, give it a trz or make another question, you now have a fiddle link which you can add